# Can I replace my local .git with a remote .git for the same repository?

Tags: git, github

My git directory is corrupt, the remote is fine.  Can I just overwrite my local .git with the remote?

Comment: Obvious question -- why don't you just re-clone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the corruption, I'd say yes.  My first attempt would be to copy just the `.git/objects` directory and hope any local objects you want to preserve aren't in corrupt local packs.

```
cp -Rf upstream/.git/objects .git
```

This way, anything that's still good in your local repo (history, logs, config, what not) remains.  After that, you can remove any corrupted objects (and packs -- unless you're in really desperate straits, recovering objects from a corrupted pack can get really nasty).  Then also and likewise copy the .git/objects from your latest backup, just in case that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to repair local copy using:

```
git fsck
```

If that does not help, just get another clone:

```
cd <outside_of_git_repo>
git clone <your_remote_git_url>
```